# Lawnchair "exists" method?

Tags: javascript, local-storage, lawnchair

I am trying to use lawnchair but the documentation on the site and github seem to say different things. Currently I need to check if an entry exists, and if not create one.

However when I run lawnchair (not special parameters as I let it choose the adaptor for me) I just get told "exists" does not exist, however I am not sure if this is a problem in the documentation saying something used to exist or if it is a real bug. I am using it within firefox at the moment while developing and works fine for everything else I have tried to do with it (other than it duplicates the entry when not using "new" initilizer.

Anyway is there a way to find out if an entry exists? be it an exists style method or a different callback from the get method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have updated to the latest version from the github source, and not the site this seems to have a fix in for the DOM adaptor to now have the exists method.